# Execute SPFeatureReceiver only on site creation

Tags: 2010, feature-activation, feature-receiver

We have recently upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and we aren't yet ready to train users on the new interface, so I've created a SPFeatureReceiver that will set the site template back to the 2007 look.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
    web.UIVersion = 3;
    web.UIVersionConfigurationEnabled = true;
    web.Update();
}
```

However this executes when the feature is activated and sets all sites to this which may end up being okay, but would like some guidance.

Is there a way to only execute this or something similar when a site is created and not just when the feature is activated, leaving any sites alone that are already created?

Instead, is the idea that the feature is technically activated when a site is created and therefore will execute when a site is created and can't do anything about this for existing sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use event recievers to do this, more specifically the SPWebEventReciever.

From Microsoft:

> An event receiver is a piece of managed code that responds to SharePoint events when specific triggering actions occur on a SharePoint object. Triggering actions include activities such as adding, updating, deleting, moving, checking in, and checking out.

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Nice find. I'll take a look at this and see if I can get something working